# is there a limit for CopyDatabase in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, copy

I'm copying 100Million records (about 97G) data to another server using copyDatabase in Mongo. Both servers have more than 500G diskspace. However, i notice although the process is still running, but the actual files are not added anymore. stop at xxxxx.11    any idea?

Comment: Have you checked `db.stats()` to see what the actual data size is?  If you've deleted a lot of records, the new copy of the database may take up less disk space (ref: [Understanding Disk Usage](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-UnderstandingDiskUsage)).

Answer (score 1):

Copy database will move collection data over, then build indexes for each collection. Building indexes on a 100GB data set can take a lot of time (especially with small amounts of RAM). It's likely that you're in the middle of a large index build.

You can check the progress by watching the logs and running `db.currentOp()` in the shell on the destination DB.

Comment: shoudl I do copy Database, or should I do mongoDump, gzip, scp over, and mongoRestore?

Comment: If you have a slowish network connection, the mongodump + zip will be faster. If it's fast between, the copyDatabase command is better.

Comment: If you can afford to take your main mongo offline or lock it, just make a dump of the database and move it over to the new server. Although `copyDatabase` work fine sometimes if there are some network issue something can go wrong. Also it's much easier to understand what is going on if oyu use the dump. Last, but not least there is less stress on the main server (except of the time of the dump).

Comment: I have pretty fast one. actually the servers are in the same network.